# Can't see the video uploaded through youtube-api

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The code doesn't give any errors but on the youtube page there is nothing. The token is ok and I can see the log saying it has finished but on youtube nothing.
How much time it take to display the video on youtube?

```
const Youtube = require("youtube-api"),
  fs = require("fs"),
  readJson = require("r-json"),
  Logger = require("bug-killer"),
  prettyBytes = require("pretty-bytes");

// I downloaded the file from OAuth2 -> Download JSON
const CREDENTIALS = readJson(`${__dirname}/credentials.json`);

// Authenticate
let oauth = Youtube.authenticate({
  type: "oauth",
  client_id: CREDENTIALS.web.client_id,
  client_secret: CREDENTIALS.web.client_secret,
  redirect_url: CREDENTIALS.web.redirect_uris[0]
});

//the token obtained with getToken.js script
var tokens = readJson(`${__dirname}/tokens.json`);

//set the token
oauth.setCredentials(tokens);

var req = Youtube.videos.insert({
  resource: {
    snippet: {
      title: "Testing",
      description: "Test video upload via YouTube API"
    },
    status: {
      privacyStatus: "public"
    }
  },
  part: "snippet,status",
  media: {
    body: fs.createReadStream("video.mp4")
  }
}, (err, data) => {
  console.log("Done.");
  process.exit();
});

setInterval(function() {
  Logger.log(`${prettyBytes(req.req.connection._bytesDispatched)} bytes uploaded.`);
}, 250);
```

Comment: There's a [NodeJS Full Sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) in the docs for uploading videos.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved, you have to enable the youtube Api v3 for your google app. Stupid issue.